# mongoDB find in query

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two entities, course and subject as follows,

```
@Document(collection = "course")
public class Course implements Serializable {
{
...........
    @Field("course_name")
    private String courseName;

   @Field("subjectIds")
    private List<String> subjectIds;
...
}


@Document(collection = "subject")
public class Subject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field("subject_name")
    private String subjectName;
...................
}
```

here "Course" contains the list of Ids of Subject. 
So , I have a subject Id say ("59ce80a4a2e7f329eccac601"), I need to find all the courses where this subject id will be present in the list of subjectIds property of Course.

Is there any way I can write this in query.

I am using mongorepository of spring

Comment: You can try `List<Course> findBySubjectIds(String subjectId);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB native query:

```
db.course.find({subjectIds: { $elemMatch: { $eq: "59ce80a4a2e7f329eccac601"}}})
```

A corresponding Spring Data MongoDB Query:

```
@Query("{'subjectIds': {\$elemMatch: {\$eq: ?0}}}")
```